# OpenSSH - Bad configuration file

Tags: bash, ssh, configuration-files, openssh

I tried to get my private/public key in order to get connected on my linux debian with putty without password.

I got no problem to generate it with this command :

> ssh-keygen -t rsa

The problems occured when I do it :

> ssh-copy-id -i /.ssh/id_dsa.pub "login@DNS_server -p "

I got this error : Bad configuration file .

Here is a screenshot of this situation (I hide my ip of course) :
[image: Problem]

Any hints about how to fix it ?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error message.
`PermitRootLogin` is an option of ssh *daemon*. You are setting up a file for ssh *client*.

Please have a look at:

- man sshd_config
- man ssh_config